# Google plus comment box integration with Angular2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-plus

I was trying to integrate google plus comment box into my MEAN 2.0 website by following [this](https://floaternet.com/gcomments) link. I configured few things as per angular2 way but not sure if that is the correct way to do that. Please guide me to integrate it as not much help i found on internet for this.

**index.html**
added below link to index.html

```
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
```

**app.ts**

```
declare let gapi:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'blogComment',
  template: `
    <div class="g-commentcount" data-href="blog/"></div>
    <div id="{{commentId}}"></div>
  `
})
export class CommentComponent /*implements OnInit */{

  commentId : string = "comments";
  constructor() {
    console.log("CommentComponent const");
    this.embedComment();
  }

  /*ngOnInit(){

  }*/

  embedComment() {
    gapi.comments.render(this.commentId, {
        href: window.location,
        width: '624',
        first_party_property: 'BLOGGER',
        view_type: 'FILTERED_POSTMOD'
    });
  }
}
```

Here is another component in the same **app.ts** file which is mapped to **"blc" router**.

```
@Component({
  providers: [CommentComponent],
  template : `
    <blogComment></blogComment>
  `
})
export class BlogComponent{
  constructor(public comment: CommentComponent) {
    console.log("BlogComponent const");
  }
} 

Router configuration
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'blc', component: BlogComponent },
 ];

const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

and finally included everything in **NgModule** like below.

```
let declarationArr : Array<any>= [ 
                     BlogHomeComponent, ckeditorClass, AuthApp, 
                     BlogNotFoundComponent, BlogComponent, BlogListComponent,
                     NewBlogComponent, CommentComponent 
                 ];
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, CKEditorModule, FormsModule, routing ],
  declarations: declarationArr,
  providers:    [ appRoutingProviders ],
  bootstrap:    [ BlogHomeComponent ]
})
export class app{}

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(app);
```

but the comment box is not at all loading into the browser.

**UPDATE**

I tried the same using normal html and js.
It is coming properly in UI with a warning::

```
'//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
cb=gapi.loaded_1:1 

'//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
```

When tries to comment something, in console it throws below error.

```
cb=gapi.loaded_1:138 POST https://apis.google.com/u/0/wm/1/_/sharebox/linkpreview/?soc-app=103&cid=0&soc-platform=1&hl=en&f.sid=712313642&_reqid=253999&rt=j 400 ()
```

And when tries to share that it throws error in UI saying::
**"Something went wrong"**

**[NOTE]** : I am in localhost. Is that the root cause? Would it get resolved if hosted?

Comment: Any suggestion from anyone here?